# Oracle Webogic Install "Invalid Java Home"

Tags: oracle, weblogic-10.x

Trying to install Oracle Weblogic on my mac for run an older project. While running the installer jar I have to select the jdk and when I do, I get "Invalid Java Home ..." See attached photos for what my setup is thus far. Thank you looking, thanks!

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: I don't know if or how much if matters, but note that in the command line session the Java version is "1.6.0_65", while the error message dialog indicates it's looking at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk". According to the [Wikipedia page for WebLogic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic_Server) version 10.3.6 supports Java 6.

Comment: WLS 10.3.6 supports Java 1.6 and 1.7 but not 1.8 and above.

Comment: Yes, I've tried 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8. No luck on any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found that I had to dig deeper into the folder, had to select the following directory.

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/` not stop at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/`